# Python - Read nth line in a matrix

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, line

What is the simplest way I can read the nth letter of a matrix?

I thought this would be possible with a simple for loop but so far I haven't had any luck.
The best I can do so far is using a count which is not exactly elegant:

```
matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1], [2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7], [1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6]]

count = 0
for n in matrix:
     print matrix[count][nth]
     count += 1
```

For example:
Read the 0th number of every row: 1, 2, 1.
Read the 4th number of every row: 6, 2, 8.

Comment: I just realized that sublists in your matrix are of different lengths, is that intentional? If so how should the row corresponding to the longest sublist's last element be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
column = [row[0] for row in matrix]
```

(for the 0th element)

Comment: That's works great. I used for n in[row[nth] for row in matrix]

Answer (score 3):

If your need to do this operation a lot you could transpose your matrix using `zip(*matrix)`

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1], [2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7], [1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6]]
>>> matrix_t = zip(*matrix)
>>> matrix_t
[(1, 2, 1), (3, 6, 6), (5, 1, 2), (2, 6, 6), (6, 2, 8), (2, 5, 2), (4, 7, 6)]
>>> matrix_t[0]
(1, 2, 1)
>>> matrix_t[3]
(2, 6, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that will handle rows of different lengths (as in your example), as well as supporting Python's special interpretation of negative indexes as relative to the end of the sequence (by changing them into`len(s) + n`):

```
NULL = type('NULL', (object,), {'__repr__': lambda self: '<NULL>'})()

def nth_elems(n):
    abs_n = abs(n)
    return [row[n] if abs_n < len(row) else NULL for row in matrix]

matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1], [2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7], [1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6]]

print nth_elems(0)   # [1, 2, 1]
print nth_elems(6)   # [4, 7, 6]
print nth_elems(7)   # [1, <NULL>, <NULL>]
print nth_elems(-1)  # [1, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1], [2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7], [1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6]]

In [2]: nth=0

In [3]: [row[nth] for row in matrix]
Out[3]: [1, 2, 1]

In [4]: nth=4

In [5]: [row[nth] for row in matrix]
Out[5]: [6, 2, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using list comprehension:

```
[x[0] for x in matrix]
```

Which is basically, equal to:

```
for x in matrix:
    print x[0]
```

You can also make it a function:

```
def getColumn(lst, col):
    return [i[col] for i in lst]
```

Demo:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1], [2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7], [1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6]]
>>> def getColumn(lst, col):
    return [i[col] for i in lst]

>>> getColumn(matrix, 0)
[1, 2, 1]
>>> getColumn(matrix, 5)
[2, 5, 2]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will work well here:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1], [2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7], [1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6]]
>>> # Get all the 0th indexes
>>> a = [item[0] for item in matrix]
>>> a
[1, 2, 1]
>>> # Get all the 4th indexes
>>> b = [item[4] for item in matrix]
>>> b
[6, 2, 8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is likely not doing what you expect.  n is not an integer.  It is the current row.
I think what you wanted to do was:

```
for row in matrix:
    print row[0], row[4]
```

This prints,

```
1 6
2 2
1 8
```

Also, strictly speaking, matrix is a list of lists.  To *really* have a matrix you might need to use numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are not intended to be used like this. Using list comprehension may cause both memory and CPU issues if the data is sufficiently big. Consider using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) if this is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use zip:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1], [2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7], [1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6]]
>>> zip(*matrix)[0]
(1, 2, 1)
>>> zip(*matrix)[4]
(6, 2, 8)
```